# Usage of ! in a Haskell type

Tags: haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the exclamation mark mean in a Haskell declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993112/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-mean-in-a-haskell-declaration)

In Alex the generated boilerplate code includes

```
data AlexPosn = AlexPn !Int  -- absolute character offset
                       !Int  -- line number
                       !Int  -- column number
```

What does the ! in front of the Int indicate?

Comment: exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993112/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-mean-in-a-haskell-declaration

Answer (score 3):

It´s a [strictness flag](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Keywords#.21) as oposed to lazy evaluation.