# What is Weak Head Normal Form?

Tags: haskell, definition, strictness, weak-head-normal-form

What does **Weak Head Normal Form** (WHNF) mean? What does **Head Normal form** (HNF) and **Normal Form** (NF) mean?

[Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/concurrent-and-multicore-programming.html) states:

> The familiar `seq` function evaluates an expression to what we
> call *head normal form* (abbreviated HNF). It stops once it reaches
> the outermost constructor (the "head"). This is distinct from *normal
> form* (NF), in which an expression is completely evaluated.
>
> You will also hear Haskell programmers refer to *weak* head normal
> form (WHNF). For normal data, weak head normal form is the same as
> head normal form. The difference only arises for functions, and is too
> abstruse to concern us here.

I have read a few resources and definitions ([Haskell Wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Graph_reduction#Weak_Head_Normal_Form) and [Haskell Mail List](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/beginners/2010-February/003396.html) and [Free Dictionary](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Weak+Head+Normal+Form)) but I don't get it. Can someone perhaps give an example or provide a layman definition?

I am guessing it would be similar to:

```
WHNF = thunk : thunk

HNF = 0 : thunk 

NF = 0 : 1 : 2 : 3 : []
```

How do `seq` and `($!)` relate to WHNF and HNF?

### Update

I am still confused. I know some of the answers say to ignore HNF. From reading the various definitions it seems that there is no difference between regular data in WHNF and HNF. However, it does seem like there is a difference when it comes to a function. If there was no difference, why is `seq` necessary for `foldl'`?

Another point of confusion is from the Haskell Wiki, which states that `seq` reduces to WHNF, and will do nothing to the following example. Then they say that they have to use `seq` to force the evaluation. Is that not forcing it to HNF?

> Common newbie stack overflowing code:
>
> ```
> myAverage = uncurry (/) . foldl' (\(acc, len) x -> (acc+x, len+1)) (0,0)
> ```
>
> People who understand seq and weak head normal form (whnf) can immediately understand what goes wrong here. `(acc+x, len+1)` is already in whnf, so the `seq` (in the definition of `foldl'`), which reduces a value to whnf, does nothing to this. This code will build up thunks just like the original `foldl` example, they'll just be inside a tuple. The solution is just to force the
> components of the tuple,  e.g.
>
> ```
> myAverage = uncurry (/) . foldl' 
>           (\(acc, len) x -> acc `seq` len `seq` (acc+x, len+1)) (0,0)
> ```

-[Haskell Wiki on Stackoverflow](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Stack_overflow)

Comment: Generally we speak of WHNF and RNF. (RNF being what you call NF)

Comment: @monadic What does the R in RNF stand for?

Comment: @dave4420: Reduced

Comment: These days also WFH is a thing.

Answer (score 442, accepted):

I'll try to give an explanation in simple terms. As others have pointed out, head normal form does not apply to Haskell, so I will not consider it here.

### Normal form

An expression in normal form is fully evaluated, and no sub-expression could be evaluated any further (i.e. it contains no un-evaluated thunks).

These expressions are all in normal form:

```
42
(2, "hello")
\x -> (x + 1)
```

These expressions are not in normal form:

```
1 + 2                 -- we could evaluate this to 3
(\x -> x + 1) 2       -- we could apply the function
"he" ++ "llo"         -- we could apply the (++)
(1 + 1, 2 + 2)        -- we could evaluate 1 + 1 and 2 + 2
```

### Weak head normal form

An expression in weak head normal form has been evaluated to the outermost data constructor or lambda abstraction (the *head*). Sub-expressions *may or may not have been evaluated*. Therefore, every normal form expression is also in weak head normal form, though the opposite does not hold in general.

To determine whether an expression is in weak head normal form, we only have to look at the outermost part of the expression. If it's a data constructor or a lambda, it's in weak head normal form. If it's a function application, it's not.

These expressions are in weak head normal form:

```
(1 + 1, 2 + 2)       -- the outermost part is the data constructor (,)
\x -> 2 + 2          -- the outermost part is a lambda abstraction
'h' : ("e" ++ "llo") -- the outermost part is the data constructor (:)
```

As mentioned, all the normal form expressions listed above are also in weak head normal form.

These expressions are not in weak head normal form:

```
1 + 2                -- the outermost part here is an application of (+)
(\x -> x + 1) 2      -- the outermost part is an application of (\x -> x + 1)
"he" ++ "llo"        -- the outermost part is an application of (++)
```

## Stack overflows

Evaluating an expression to weak head normal form may require that other expressions be evaluated to WHNF first. For example, to evaluate `1 + (2 + 3)` to WHNF, we first have to evaluate `2 + 3`. If evaluating a single expression leads to too many of these nested evaluations, the result is a stack overflow.

This happens when you build up a large expression that does not produce any data constructors or lambdas until a large part of it has been evaluated. These are often caused by this kind of usage of `foldl`:

```
foldl (+) 0 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
 = foldl (+) (0 + 1) [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
 = foldl (+) ((0 + 1) + 2) [3, 4, 5, 6]
 = foldl (+) (((0 + 1) + 2) + 3) [4, 5, 6]
 = foldl (+) ((((0 + 1) + 2) + 3) + 4) [5, 6]
 = foldl (+) (((((0 + 1) + 2) + 3) + 4) + 5) [6]
 = foldl (+) ((((((0 + 1) + 2) + 3) + 4) + 5) + 6) []
 = (((((0 + 1) + 2) + 3) + 4) + 5) + 6
 = ((((1 + 2) + 3) + 4) + 5) + 6
 = (((3 + 3) + 4) + 5) + 6
 = ((6 + 4) + 5) + 6
 = (10 + 5) + 6
 = 15 + 6
 = 21
```

Notice how it has to go quite deep before it can get the expression into weak head normal form.

You may wonder, why does not Haskell reduce the inner expressions ahead of time? That is because of Haskell's laziness. Since it cannot be assumed in general that every subexpression will be needed, expressions are evaluated from the outside in.

(GHC has a strictness analyzer that will detect some situations where a subexpression is always needed and it can then evaluate it ahead of time. This is only an optimization, however, and you should not rely on it to save you from overflows).

This kind of expression, on the other hand, is completely safe:

```
data List a = Cons a (List a) | Nil
foldr Cons Nil [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
 = Cons 1 (foldr Cons Nil [2, 3, 4, 5, 6])  -- Cons is a constructor, stop.
```

To avoid building these large expressions when we know all the subexpressions will have to be evaluated, we want to force the inner parts to be evaluated ahead of time.

## `seq`

`seq` is a special function that is used to force expressions to be evaluated. Its semantics are that `seq x y` means that whenever `y` is evaluated to weak head normal form, `x` is also evaluated to weak head normal form.

It is among other places used in the definition of `foldl'`, the strict variant of `foldl`.

```
foldl' f a []     = a
foldl' f a (x:xs) = let a' = f a x in a' `seq` foldl' f a' xs
```

Each iteration of `foldl'` forces the accumulator to WHNF. It therefore avoids building up a large expression, and it therefore avoids overflowing the stack.

```
foldl' (+) 0 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
 = foldl' (+) 1 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
 = foldl' (+) 3 [3, 4, 5, 6]
 = foldl' (+) 6 [4, 5, 6]
 = foldl' (+) 10 [5, 6]
 = foldl' (+) 15 [6]
 = foldl' (+) 21 []
 = 21                           -- 21 is a data constructor, stop.
```

But as the example on HaskellWiki mentions, this does not save you in all cases, as the accumulator is only evaluated to WHNF. In the example below, the accumulator is a tuple, so it will only force evaluation of the tuple constructor, and not `acc` or `len`.

```
f (acc, len) x = (acc + x, len + 1)

foldl' f (0, 0) [1, 2, 3]
 = foldl' f (0 + 1, 0 + 1) [2, 3]
 = foldl' f ((0 + 1) + 2, (0 + 1) + 1) [3]
 = foldl' f (((0 + 1) + 2) + 3, ((0 + 1) + 1) + 1) []
 = (((0 + 1) + 2) + 3, ((0 + 1) + 1) + 1)  -- tuple constructor, stop.
```

To avoid this, we must make it so that evaluating the tuple constructor forces evaluation of `acc` and `len`. We do this by using `seq`.

```
f' (acc, len) x = let acc' = acc + x
                      len' = len + 1
                  in  acc' `seq` len' `seq` (acc', len')

foldl' f' (0, 0) [1, 2, 3]
 = foldl' f' (1, 1) [2, 3]
 = foldl' f' (3, 2) [3]
 = foldl' f' (6, 3) []
 = (6, 3)                    -- tuple constructor, stop.
```

Comment: Head normal form requires that the body of a lambda is reduced as well, while weak head normal form does not have this requirement. So `\x -> 1 + 1` is WHNF but not HNF.

Comment: Wikipedia states HNF is "[a] term is in head normal form if there is no beta-redex in head position". Is Haskell "weak" because it does not beta-redex sub-expressions?

Comment: How do strict data constructors come into the play? Are they just like calling `seq` on their arguments?

Comment: @Bergi: Yes, data constructors with strict fields will force those fields to be evaluated to WHNF when the constructor itself is evaluated.

Comment: You say 1 + 2 is not NF, however you also say 1 + 2 is not WHNF, so what is it?

Comment: @CaptainObvious: 1 + 2 is neither NF nor WHNF. Expressions aren't always in a normal form.

Comment: "Notice how it has to go quite deep before it can get the expression into weak head normal form." — it only appears to be in WHNF on the last line (21), right?

Comment: @egdmitry: Yes. The point is that in order to get there, it first has to evaluate all the recursive calls to `foldl` before it can do the sums, generating a lot of unnecessary thunks in the process.

Comment: In your second example of `foldl'` with the tuple, could you potentially use deepSeq inside `foldl'` which would subsume the `seq` usage inside `f`?

Comment: You wrote `data List = Cons a (List a) | Nil`. Did you forget the type parameter here - `data List a = ...`?

Comment: @mucaho: Indeed I did. Good catch!

Comment: When I try your last example in ghci (`foldl'` with `f (acc, len) x = (acc + x, len +1)`) it gives me (6,3) directly, without using `seq`. How come?

Comment: @Zorobay: In order to print the result, GHCi ends up evaluating the expression completely to NF, not just to WHNF. One way to tell the difference between the two variants is to enable memory stats with `:set +s`. You can then see that [`foldl' f` ends up allocating more thunks than `foldl' f'`](https://pastebin.com/3GAyftXf).

Answer (score 44):

The section on [Thunks and Weak Head Normal Form](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Laziness#Thunks_and_Weak_head_normal_form) in the Haskell Wikibooks [description of laziness](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Laziness) provides a very good description of WHNF along with this helpful depiction:

[image: Evaluating the value (4, [1, 2]) step by step. The first stage is completely unevaluated; all subsequent forms are in WHNF, and the last one is also in normal form.]

> Evaluating the value (4, [1, 2]) step by step. The first stage is
>   completely unevaluated; all subsequent forms are in WHNF, and the last
>   one is also in normal form.

Comment: I know people say to ignore head normal form, but can you give an example in that diagram you have what a head normal form looks like?

Answer (score 35):

Haskell programs are *expressions* and they are run by performing *evaluation*.

To evaluate an expression, replace all function applications by their definitions. The order in which you do this does not matter much, but it's still important: start with the outermost application and proceed from left to right; this is called *lazy evaluation*.

Example:

```
   take 1 (1:2:3:[])
=> { apply take }
   1 : take (1-1) (2:3:[])
=> { apply (-)  }
   1 : take 0 (2:3:[])
=> { apply take }
   1 : []
```

Evaluation stops when there are no more function applications left to replace. The result is in **normal form** (or *reduced normal form*, RNF). No matter in which order you evaluate an expression, you will always end up with the same normal form (but only if the evaluation terminates).

There is a slightly different description for lazy evaluation. Namely, it says that you should evaluate everything to **weak head normal form** only. There are precisely three cases for an expression to be in WHNF:

- A constructor: `constructor expression_1 expression_2 ...`
- A built-in function with too few arguments, like `(+) 2` or `sqrt`
- A lambda-expression: `\x -> expression`

In other words, the head of the expression (i.e. the outermost function application) cannot be evaluated any further, but the function argument may contain unevaluated expressions.

Examples of WHNF:

```
3 : take 2 [2,3,4]   -- outermost function is a constructor (:)
(3+1) : [4..]        -- ditto
\x -> 4+5            -- lambda expression
```

---

Notes

1. The "head" in WHNF does not refer to the head of a list, but to the outermost function application.
2. Sometimes, people call unevaluated expressions "thunks", but I don't think that's a good way to understand it.
3. **Head normal form** (HNF) is irrelevant for Haskell. It differs from WHNF in that the bodies of lambda expressions are also evaluated to some extent.

Comment: Is the use of `seq` in `foldl'` force the evaluation from WHNF to HNF?

Comment: @snmcdonald: No, Haskell does not make use of HNF. Evaluating `seq expr1 expr2` will evaluate the first expression `expr1` to WHNF before evaluating the second expression `expr2`.

Answer (score 26):

A good explanation with examples is given at http://foldoc.org/Weak+Head+Normal+Form  Head normal form simplifies even the bits of an expression inside of a function abstraction, while "weak" head normal form stops at function abstractions.

From the source, if you have:

```
\ x -> ((\ y -> y+x) 2)
```

that is in weak head normal form, but not head normal form... because the possible application is stuck inside of a function that can't be evaluated yet.

Actual head normal form would be difficult to implement efficiently.  It would require poking around inside of functions.  So the advantage of weak head normal form is that you can still implement functions as an opaque type, and hence it's more compatible with compiled languages and optimization.

Answer (score 12):

The WHNF does not want the body of lambdas to be evaluated, so

```
WHNF = \a -> thunk
HNF = \a -> a + c
```

`seq` wants its first argument to be in WHNF, so

```
let a = \b c d e -> (\f -> b + c + d + e + f) b
    b = a 2
in seq b (b 5)
```

evaluates to

```
\d e -> (\f -> 2 + 5 + d + e + f) 2
```

instead of, what would be using HNF

```
\d e -> 2 + 5 + d + e + 2
```

Comment: Or I misunderstand the example, or you mix 1 and 2 in the WHNF and HNF.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, suppose you have some sort of thunk, `t`.

Now, if we want to evaluate `t` to WHNF or NHF, which are the same except for functions, we would find that we get something like

`t1 : t2` where `t1` and `t2` are thunks. In this case, `t1` would be your `0` (or rather, a thunk to `0` given no extra unboxing)

`seq` and `$!` evalute WHNF. Note that

```
f $! x = seq x (f x)
```

Comment: @snmcdonald Ignore HNF. seq says that when this is evaluated to WHNF, evaluate the first argument to WHNF.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old question, but here is an explicit mathematical definition of WHNF, HNF, and NF. In the **pure lambda calculus**:

- A term is in NF if it is of the form

  ```
  λ x1. λ x2. ... λ xn. (x t1 t2 ... tm)
  ```

  where `x` is a variable, and `t1, t2, ..., tm` are in NF.
- A term is in HNF if it is of the form

  ```
  λ x1. λ x2. ... λ xn. (x e1 e2 ... em)
  ```

  where `x` is a variable, and `e1, e2, ..., em` are arbitrary terms.
- A term is in WHNF if it is either a lambda term `λ x. e` for any term `e` or if it is of the form

  ```
  x e1 e2 ... em
  ```

  where `x` is a variable and `e1, e2, ..., em` are arbitrary terms.

---

Now consider a **programming language with *constructors*** `a,b,c...` of arity `na, nb, nc...`, which means that whenever `t1, t2, ..., tm` are in NF, then the term `a t1 t2 ... tm` where `m = na` is a redex and can be evaluated. For example, the addition constructor `+` in Haskell has arity `2`, because it only *evaluates* when it is given two arguments in normal form (in this case integers, which can themselves be considered as nullary constructors).

- A term is in NF if it is of the form

  ```
  λ x1. λ x2. ... λ xn. (x t1 t2 ... tm)
  ```

  where `x` is either a variable or a constructor of arity `n` with `m < n`, and `t1, t2, ..., tm` are in NF.
- A term is in HNF if it is of the form

  ```
  λ x1. λ x2. ... λ xn. (x e1 e2 ... em)
  ```

  where `x` is either a variable or a constructor of arity `n`, and `e1, e2, ... em` are arbitrary terms *so long as the first `n` arguments are **not all** in NF.*
- A term is in WHNF if it is either a lambda term `λ x. e` for any term `e` or if it is of the form

  ```
  x e1 e2 ... em
  ```

  where `x` is either a variable or a constructor of arity `n`, and `e1, e2, ... em` are arbitrary terms *so long as the first `n` arguments are **not all** in NF.*

---

In particular, any term in NF is in HNF, and any term in HNF is in WHNF, but not conversely.

Comment: Why do you require that the first `n` arguments are not all in NF?

Comment: @dfeuer Take as example `+`, with arity two, then the WHNF of `(+ 2 3)` is `5` because `2` and `3` are in NF, but the WHNF of `(+ 2 (+ 2 1))` is `(+ 2 (+ 2 1))` because `(+ 2 1)` is not in NF. If the first `n` arguments `e_1 ... e_n` of a constructor `c` (of arity `n`) are in NF, then `(c e_1 ... e_n)` may be a reduct, as in the case of `+`. I should have pointed out that by constructor I mean a constructor with a reduction rule.

Comment: It looks to me like you don't understand the definition of WHNF. Tomek Dobrzynski's answer points it out in chapter 11 of [this text](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/1987/01/slpj-book-1987-small.pdf). `(+ 2 (+ 2 1))` is not in WHNF because it's a fully applied non-constructor function (`+` has an arity of 2 and is applied to 2 arguments).

Comment: @dfeuer Please look at page 10 of the text for the definition of redex. `(+ 2 (+ 2 1))` is not a redex.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I doubt they intended the definition on page 10 to apply there. The whole idea of lazy graph reduction is to reduce expressions to WHNF in the sense that they are either 1. a lambda expression, 2. a partial application, or 3. a fully applied data constructor. The graph reduction engine is not going to come to `(+ 2 (+ 2 1))` and just throw up it's hands. (Cont)

Comment: (Cont'd)  So one of two things must be going on: 1. An expression like `(+ 2 (+ 2 1))` is already excluded by a compilation step that rewrites it to (switching to Haskell notation)  `case 2 + 1 of !r -> 2 + r`, or 2. A more expansive definition of redex is in scope, explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: @dfeuer WHNF is not necessarily the end result of a lazy (or other) evaluation strategy, but rather an intermediate step.

Answer (score 2):

In an implementation of graph reduction, lazy evaluation to HNF forces you to deal with the name capture problem of lambda calculus, whereas lazy evaluation to WHNF lets you avoid it.

This is explained in [Chapter 11 of The Implementation of Functional Programming Languages](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/1987/01/slpj-book-1987-small.pdf) by Simon Peyton Jones.

Answer (score 1):

Head normal form means there is no head redex

`(λx.((λy.y+x)b))b`

Reduces to: R, for redex (and yes there's another redex inside it but this is irrelevant). This is a head redex because it's the leftmost redex (the only redex), and there are no lambda terms before it (variables or lambda expressions (applications or abstractions)), only 0 to n abstractors (if R is a redex `(λx.A)B` the abstractor of R is `λx`), in this case 0.

Because there's a head redex it is not in HNF and it is therefore also not in NF because there's a redex.

WHNF means that it is a lambda abstraction or in HNF. The above is not in HNF and it is not a lambda abstraction, but an application, and is therefore not in WHNF.

`λx.((λy.y+x)b)b` is in WHNF

It is a lambda abstraction, but not in HNF because there is a head `λx.Rb`

Reduce to `λx.((b+x)b)`. There is no redex therefore it is in normal form.

Consider `λx.((λy.zyx)b)`, it simplifies to `λx.R`, so it is not in HNF. `λx.(k(λy.zyx)b)` simplifies to `λx.kR` therefore it is in HNF but not NF.

All NF are in HNF and WHNF. All HNF are WHNF.