# Any way to "visualize" a thunk/function? Or how to view a function for a general argument

Tags: function, haskell

I'm not totally sure how to ask this, but is there a way to show the structure of a thunk?

For example

```
f x = x + 2
g x = 3 x

compo x = f (g x)

ans = compo 5
-- result: (3 * 5) + 2 = 17
```

Is there any way I could "see" the thunk for `ans`?  As in, I could see the process of the beta reduction for `compo` or like the "general" form.

I would like to see, for example:

```
compo n
--> (3 * n) + 2
```

As in, if I had a function `compo x`, I would like to view that it is decomposed to `(3*n)+2`.

For example, in Mathematica:

```
f[x_] := x+2;
g[x_] := 3*x;
compo[x_] := f[g[x]];

compo[n]
(%
  --> (3 * n) + 2
%)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is the **ghc-vis** package on hackage which show a visualization of your heap and of unevaluated thunks.

See the [package on hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-vis) or the [Homepage](http://felsin9.de/nnis/ghc-vis/) (which contains rather impressive examples).

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to see the sequence of reductions, you could try using the GHCi interactive debugger. (It's in the GHC manual somewhere.) It's not nearly as easy as your typical IDE debugger, but it more or less works...

Answer (score 1):

In general (we are talking about Haskell code) I think it has no sense, the final thunk stream will be different for different input data and, on the other hand, functions are expanded partially (functions are not only simple expressions).

Anyway, you can simulate it (but ugly)

```
Prelude> :set -XQuasiQuotes
Prelude> :set -XTemplateHaskell
Prelude> import Language.Haskell.TH
Prelude> import Language.Haskell.TH.Quote
Prelude> runQ [| $([|\x -> 3 * x|]) . $([|\y -> y + 2|]) |]
InfixE (Just (LamE [VarP x_0] (InfixE (Just (LitE (IntegerL 3))) (VarE GHC.Num.*) (Just (VarE x_0))))) (VarE GHC.Base..) (Just (LamE [VarP y_1] (InfixE (Just (VarE y_1)) (VarE GHC.Num.+) (Just (LitE (IntegerL 2))))))
```