# Recordwildcards crashes at runtime in yesod app

Tags: haskell, yesod

I ran into the following error which is quite surprising. I added a field to the `AppSettings` in a Yesod app (using the Yesod scaffholding) and to my surprise, everything compiled even though I didn't do anything else (I was expecting to have to add somewhere a default value to the construction of `AppSettings`, but not). I got a runtime error instead telling me that a field was missing. 
It appears that the only construction to `AppSetting` uses the `RecordWildCards` extension and looks like `AppSettings{..}`. Not defining the new field didn't generate an error but a warning (I didn't see it, because I was running test in continuous mode using `stack test --file-watch`). How is that possible ?
I try to reproduce the problem in a simple file and I get an error not a warning. So why do I get a warning for Yesod ? Is it a compilation flag or something ?

## Edit

This is not specific to Yesod. I've made the test again with a simple file and it generates a warning not an error.

Comment: "Is it a compilation flag or something ?" - probably. This seems like a `stack` issue, which settings is it passing to ghc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to changelog in GHC, "that not a bug, it's a feature": https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5334

You can change this behavior by changing type of your fields to strict (prepend a `!` to type name - like `!Int`) - however, then you lose laziness (more about effects of strict types: [Advantages of strict fields in data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576795/advantages-of-strict-fields-in-data-types))

Of course, you can also make it an error by slamming in `-Werror` compilation option, but then you need to be very strict about your code (no unused imports, no unused variables, even when unpacking a record etc.), or get rid of `-Wall` and turn on only warnings you perceive as important.