# Module imports form a cycle

Tags: haskell

Hello i was wondering how do you solve circular dependency in Haskell

I have :
**Module for a type.**

```
module Company where

import Tclass

data Worker=Worker{
    age::Int,
    name::String,
    title::Title,
    income::Int
}

data Title=Manager | Dev | Tester deriving (Show)


data Company=Company{
    cname::String,
    people::[Worker],
    yf::Int
}
```

**Module for the instance of the typeclass**

```
module Tclass where
import System.Environment
import Company

class Console a where
    wLine::a->IO()
    rLine::IO String->a

instance Show Worker where
    show w="to be defined"
    print =putStr . show
```

If i just want to load the type in ghci and use it ; how do i import them without getting the error:

```
Module imports form a cycle:
         module `Tclass' (.\Tclass.hs)
        imports `Company' (Company.hs)
  which imports `Tclass' (.\Tclass.hs)
```

**P.S** I have tried creating a auxiliary module that imports the two modules and the two modules would import it too,but no luck with this one either :

```
module Au where
 import Tclass
 import Company

module Company
 import Au

module Tclass 
 import Au
```

Comment: It looks like the first module should not import the second, can you remove the line `import Tclass` and retry?

Comment: But if i do not import the `TClass ` inside the `Company` module i can not use instance of `Show` for `Worker` type.

Comment: Then can you move the Show instance to the other module ? defining an instance in another module than the data definition is bad practice (you'll have the orphan instance warning)

Comment: Oh Ok i do not know yet good or bad practices in Haskell.Still a beginner.I thought that you can have the types in their modules ,and a module contianing all instances of a typeclass.

Comment: You can have the types in a specific module, but with their instances.

Comment: It's not part of the question but reading your code I would suggest that you read about strict fields in data records : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576795/advantages-of-strict-fields-in-data-types it might be helpful here.

Comment: Minor note: mutually recursive modules can be defined in GHC using `.hs-boot` files, but if possible it better to avoid them. Instances should be defined, when possible, in the module defining the `class` or in the module defining the type. Putting the instance elsewhere makes it a so-called "orphan" instance, which slows down compilation time, and is hard to find by other programmers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving the Show instance to the other module, you can break the cycle:

```
module Tclass where
import System.Environment
import Company

class Console a where
    wLine::a->IO()
    rLine::IO String->a
```

and

```
module Company where

data Worker=Worker{
    age::Int,
    name::String,
    title::Title,
    income::Int
}
instance Show Worker where
    show w="to be defined"
    print =putStr . show 

data Title=Manager | Dev | Tester deriving (Show)

data Company=Company{
    cname::String,
    people::[Worker],
    yf::Int
}
```