# How to fold lists of lazy types ([IO a])?

Tags: performance, haskell

I don't know whether it is a valid term 'lazy types'. But still, IO is lazy so in

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.List

result :: IO Double
result = foldl1' (liftM2 (+)) $ map return [1..10000000]

result' :: IO Double
result' = return $ foldl1' (+) [1..10000000]
```

`result` is slow and uses a lot of memory, unlike `result'`. How shall I fold `[IO a]` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`result` constructs one big `IO Double` value without evaluating any of the intermediate results, that only happens when the total result is demanded, e.g. for printing. `foldl'` evaluates the intermediate results to weak head normal form, that is, to the outermost constructor or lambda. Since (in GHC), `IO a` has the constructor `IO`, the intermediate results of the fold have the form

```
IO (some computation combined with another)
```

and the expression under the `IO` gets more complicated at each step.

To avoid that, you have to force not only the intermediate `IO` values, but also the values that they return,

```
main :: IO ()
main = foldlM' (\a -> fmap (a+)) 0 (map return [1.0 .. 10000000]) >>= print

foldlM' :: Monad m => (a -> b -> m a) -> a -> [b] -> m a
foldlM' foo a [] = return a
foldlM' foo a (b:bs) = do
    c <- foo a b
    c `seq` foldlM' foo c bs
```

works for your example.

Comment: interesting, your code works ok when compiled (with O2), but in ghci it eats memory, though not as much as hammar's variant.

Comment: Which GHC version? If I run it interpreted with 7.2.2, top reports 50m resident and 105m virtual memory. That's not too bad.

Comment: I've just installed 7.2.2, after launching the code system monitor says ghc takes 1.4 GiB. And it doesn't give them back. I thought ghci in 7.2.2 should give the memory back.

Comment: Yes, as of 7.0, memory is (supposed to be) handed back if no longer used. Have you bound anything to a name at the prompt? ksysguard only reports 25m, by the way.

Comment: no, just `ghci Test.hs` and here I've run `main`. Ubuntu 11.10, GHC 7.2.2 64 bit binary from the site.

Comment: Ah, okay, so you've bound it in the file. So `main` is still in scope, and it's a CAF, so the memory occupied by it cannot be released. And since it's `IO`, `main` is not the final outcome `return number`, but the entire computation to produce it (for all the compiler knows, it could have side effects that ought to be repeated). Thus it's a huge `IO thunk`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `foldl'` only reduces the accumulator to [WHNF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872898/haskell-what-is-weak-head-normal-form) at each step. In this case the accumulator is an `IO` action, and evaluating an `IO` action does not force the value within, so you end up with the typical huge thunk that doesn't get evaluated until the end.

The solution is to use something stricter than `liftM2`, for example:

```
result'' :: IO Double
result'' = foldl1' f $ map return [1..100000]
    where f mx my = do x <- mx; y <- my; return $! x + y
```

Here's a quick benchmark:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.List
import Criterion.Main

result :: IO Double
result = foldl1' (liftM2 (+)) $ map return [1..100000]

result' :: IO Double
result' = return $ foldl1' (+) [1..100000]

result'' :: IO Double
result'' = foldl1' f $ map return [1..100000]
  where f mx my = do x <- mx; y <- my; return $! x + y

main = defaultMain [ bench "result" $ whnfIO result
                   , bench "result'" $ whnfIO result'
                   , bench "result''" $ whnfIO result'' ]
```

Result:

```
[...]
benchmarking result
collecting 100 samples, 1 iterations each, in estimated 37.32438 s
mean: 136.3221 ms, lb 131.4504 ms, ub 140.8238 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 23.92297 ms, lb 22.00429 ms, ub 25.53803 ms, ci 0.950

benchmarking result'
collecting 100 samples, 14 iterations each, in estimated 6.046951 s
mean: 4.349027 ms, lb 4.338121 ms, ub 4.367363 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 70.96316 us, lb 49.01322 us, ub 113.0399 us, ci 0.950

benchmarking result''
collecting 100 samples, 2 iterations each, in estimated 8.131099 s
mean: 41.89589 ms, lb 40.67513 ms, ub 43.52798 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 7.194770 ms, lb 5.758892 ms, ub 8.529327 ms, ci 0.950
```

As you can see, this is still slower than the pure code, but not by as much.

Comment: hammar, could you please try it with `10000000`? I still have it slow with such number.

Comment: @Yrogirg: It uses too much memory for my poor netbook, I'm afraid. Though, I added Daniel's answer to my benchmark and it took about 19ms, twice as fast as mine. You can run the benchmarks yourself by installing [criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion).

Comment: yes, that what I meant --- it took all my 6 Gb, while pure code doesn't consume memory.

Comment: I get a stack overflow for `result` and `result''` with upper bound 1000000. The space consumption is almost certainly due to the lists `[1 .. n]` and `map return [1 .. n]` being top-level CAFs.

Answer (score 0):

based on the Daniel's answer the variant which allows to straightforwardly implement an analog of `foldl1'`:

```
result'' :: IO Double
result'' = foldlM1' (+) (map return [1.0 .. 100000000])

foldlM' :: Monad m => (a -> b -> a) -> m a -> [m b] -> m a
foldlM' foo ma [] = ma
foldlM' foo ma (mb:mbs) = do
    c <- (liftM2 foo) ma mb
    c `seq` foldlM' foo (return c) mbs

foldlM1' foo (x:xs) = foldlM' foo x xs
foldlM1' _ []       = error "Empty list for foldlM1'"
```