# Haskell: seq, par, rseq, rpar signatures

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to understand parallelism in Haskell and one thing that I'm curious about is the signature difference between `seq` / `rseq` and `par` / `rpar`

```
seq :: a -> b -> b
par :: a -> b -> b

rseq :: a -> Eval a
rpar :: a -> Eval a
```

I understand that `rseq` and `rpar` are monadic versions so they bear the `Eval` part. **But why aren't `seq` and `par` both just `a -> a`?** Kind of like strict identities... A reason for "encomplication" should exist.

There also seems to be a lot of mystery around `seq`. Some sources say `a` is evaluated when `b` is evaluated (to WHNF). Other sources say `a` is evaluated at call time. It's really confusing! While it's possible to test-drive some things with actual tests I'm afraid I can easily misinterpret the results.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046590/the-seq-function-and-strictness) for information on `seq` and why it is a 2-argument-function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already a function of type `a -> a` that is strict, namely `id`.
Haskell is non-strict, so the only reason a function is called is when you need the result of the function, so when `id y` is called you need that value.  In a similar way, when `seq x y` is called it's because you need that value.

The operational semantics of `seq` is not specified in Haskell, which might be why you find it mysterious.  And easier function to understand is `pseq`.  The `pseq` function evaluates its first argument to WHNF and then returns its second argument.
The `seq` function might do the same as `pseq`, but it might also not.
It is defined by its denotational semantics instead (section 6.2 in the Haskell report):

```
seq ⊥ b = ⊥
seq a b = b, if a /= ⊥
```

From this we can conclude that `seq` is strict in both arguments.  For strict functions it's quite possible for the caller to evaluate the arguments since this makes no semantic difference.  So in a call to `seq` the caller might evaluate any combination of the arguments in any order.

Answer (score 0):

To put it short, `seq` doen *not* evaluate its argument, it just introduces a dependency between `a` and `b`: whenever `b` is evaluated to WHNF, `a` is also evaluated.

`par` does this the same way: whenever `b` is evaluated `a` *may* be evaluated parallelly.

This semantic is the reason why `seq a a` and hence `seq a` is useless. Also, allowing `seq` to directly evaluate `a` would break the purity.

Comment: Can you elaborate why would evaluation of a thunk break the purity? I believe thunks and values are meant to be interchangeable and the difference is only in operational semantics. And this does not answer why `rpar` and `rseq` are made differently.

Comment: `rseq` and `rpar` create a dependency between the evaluation of the `Eval` value they return and the evaluation of their argument. This works in the context of `Eval`, because `(>>=)` for `Eval` forces evaluation of its first argument before passing a value to its second argument.