# Implementing an infinite list with seq to improve time complexity in Haskell

Tags: haskell, seq

I don't quite understand how seq exactly works and how to implement a function using seq.
So as an exercise, if I want to implement a function that generates a list starting with a number a.

for example, I'm using the following function

```
countup n = n : countup (n+1)
```

and trying to get [1, 2, 3, 4 ...] (starting from 1, just increment 1 and add to the list) as an infinite lazy list.
How should I do this?

**UPDATED:**

I'm trying to make (take k (countup 0)) to use O(1) space.
Here, take function is as follows:

```
take k (x:xl) = 
    if k==0
    then x
    else take (k-1) xl
```

Comment: You don’t need `seq` to do that. _Especially_ not if you want your list to be lazy! Just do `countup n = [n..]`.

Comment: As for learning how `seq` works, here are some useful articles you might want to check out: http://dev.stephendiehl.com/hask/#laziness https://www.fpcomplete.com/haskell/tutorial/all-about-strictness/ https://wiki.haskell.org/Seq https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046590/the-seq-function-and-strictness

Comment: @bradrn I want to minimize the space usage using seq. So I implemented a function that takes a number (an index) and a list (an infinite list) that finds an element of an index of the infinite list. And I heard I can somehow minimize the space complexity to O(1) if I use seq to implement the list?

Comment: In general, space complexity is very hard to reason about in Haskell. If your function is using more space than expected, `seq` _can_ help reduce it, but only if you use it correctly. What function are you trying to use it with?

Comment: @James: lazy functions can often also *reduce* space. Indeed, `[1..n]`, takes, if it remains unevaluated only O(1) space, it is only if you "consume" the list, that it expands, but even then not per se to *n* elements, so lazy evaluation can often *save* memory as well.

Comment: @bradrn I updated the code that I want to minimize the space complexity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
countup n = n : countup (n+1)
```

Each element of the list is created as a thunk `previousElement + 1`. So if you `take` the 1000000th or whatever element, that will be a very large thunk `(...(n + 1)... + 1)` containing ~1000000 suspensions. Even though the `:`-cells can be GC'd as soon as they are made (so traversing the list spine itself takes `O(1)` space), the elements themselves duplicate the structure of the list and so `take k (countup n)` still takes `O(k)` space.

We would like it if evaluating the `:` cells would also evaluate the elements. We can do that with

```
countup n = seq n $ n : countup (n + 1)
```

Now, when evaluating `seq n $ n : countup (n + 1)`, `seq` will cause *both* `n` and `n : countup (n + 1)` to be evaluated. Evaluating the latter does nothing (it is already evaluated), and evaluating the former performs any thunked addition so that the `+ 1`s never build up. With this definition, `take k (countup n)` takes `O(1)` space (or, really `O(log(n + k))`).

We can also write the improved function as

```
countup !n = n : countup (n + 1)
```

Comment: I tried profiling both versions of `countup` as an experiment, but I can see no difference between them in either their memory usage or their speed. Are you sure that the implementation with `seq` take less space than the one without?

Comment: Yes, quite sure. Compile `{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-} module Main where import Prelude hiding (take); countUp !x = x : countUp (x + 1); take 0 (x : _) = x; take n (_ : xs) = take (n - 1) xs; main = print =<< (flip take (countUp 0) <$> readLn)` with `ghc -O`. Then run it with `./Main +RTS -s`. Give inputs `1000`, `1000000`, `10000000`: the output (for me) shows 2 MB heap usage. Now remove the `!` and recompile. Passing `1000` still uses ~2 MB. Passing `1000000` takes ~67 MB, and `10000000` ~670 MB. Ouch! Don't know what you did, but note "profiling" can give wrong results and is unnecessary.

Comment: Yet another way to write it: ``(!:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]; a !: as = a `seq` a : as``, then `countup n = n !: countup (n + 1)`.

Comment: OK @HTNW, I’ll try that and see if it works. (Hmm… maybe our difference in results was because we used different GHC options? I compiled with `-prof` rather than `-O` so I could make a heap profile.)

Comment: Thanks! I got the first countup version countup as countup n = n `seq` n : countup (n + 1) but I wasn't sure. And thanks for the additional information on how to check heap usage :) lovely. @HTNW.

Comment: @HTNW Nope, can’t replicate your results: I get 0.2 MB for 1000, 80 MB for 1000000, 800 MB for 10000000. (See https://pastebin.com/DBNiQMZK for output.)

Comment: @bradrn You're looking at the wrong number. "Total allocations" is not a measure of memory use; it is a measure of *work*. It counts up on each allocated object but doesn't count down on deallocation. The *maximum actual memory use at a given time* is "total memory in use", which you see doesn't vary (shows 0, hah!). I.e. yes, the improved `countup` builds and burns through lots and lots of objects, but those objects are separated in time; they don't take up 800MB of actual memory (which is kind of the point: the `O(1)` behavior is because "skipped" cells are GC'd right after creation).

Comment: @bradrn E.g. if I pass 1,000,000,000, I get ~80GB of "Total allocations"... the potato I'm running it on has 4GB of RAM. If you try the non-strict one, it actually *does* try to use up all those gobs and gobs of memory... Funnily, it seems like the total allocations is about twice the max memory usage in that case, which I think might correspond to there being one retained object (the `n + 1` thunk) per two objects total (the `:` cell and the thunk).

Comment: @HTNW Thanks for the correction! Obviously I had no idea how to read that output… that’ll really help next time I need to figure out the heap usage of a program.