# Haskell how to force evaluation of Data.Map in haskell?

Tags: haskell

So I have a Map that is Strict

```
import qualified Data.Map.Strict      as Map
import qualified Data.ByteString       as BS
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C

type Key = Int
type Value = BS.ByteString

data KeyValue = KeyValue !(Map.Map Key Value)

source :: [(Key, Value)]
source = zip [0..] $ map (\x -> BS.concat $ replicate 10000 $ "alsfdd" `C.append` (C.pack $ show x)) [0..10000]
```

I am trying to get the Map to evaluate each time I put an element...

```
 putStrLn "Putting 10000 Strict ByteStrings into a Map"
 let newMap = foldr (\(k,v) i -> Map.insert k v $! i) Map.empty source
 putStrLn "Done..."
 putStrLn "Launching interactive mode"
 forever $ do
      putStrLn "Enter an integer:"
      k <- getLine
      print $ Map.lookup (read k) newMap
```

However, the Map doesn't evaluate until I get into "interactive mode" and submit a query.

The only way I can get it to evaluate is to print its size:

```
newMap <- foldM (\i (k, v) -> (print $ Map.size i) >> (return Map.insert k v i)) Map.empty source
```

How do I use `seq` or `$!` correctly?

#### More details about my actual problem that this is based off of:

I should note that in my original program, the Map is contained in a TVar and elements are inserted on IO events. So to me it doesn't make sense why if I am modifying the TVar haskell isn't forcing evaluation of the Map. My program is a multithreaded socket server with one address being the "reader" that performs a lookup. The other socket address just pushes bytestrings onto the map. I can connect 2 sockets to the inserting and 1 socket to the reader. if I insert a bunch of times, the map won't be evaluated until my reader socket looksup the value. I would like the Map to be evaluated when I am modifying the TVar. The only way that I found to do this is to print the size of the map before I modify my TVar on an insert.

EDIT:

So I tried a bang pattern, which works on the example above, but doesn't work on my server:

```
buildIndex :: Int -> ByteString -> M.Map Int ByteString -> M.Map Int ByteString

liftIO $ do indexed <- readTVarIO tvi
            let !newIndex = buildIndex nextKey serialized indexed
            atomically $ writeTVar tvi $! newIndex
```

Comment: Try `newMap \`seq\` return ()` or `evaluate newMap` (needs `Control.Exception`).

Comment: Thanks. Neither worked though. :|

Comment: I have the same answer as @Vitus and it does work. Just place ```newMap `seq` return()``` or `evaluate newMap` just after `let newMap = ...`.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using bang patterns, since it's usually the easiest way to force something to evaluate.  The problem is that while you're using strict versions of `Map` and `ByteString`, not every operation you perform is strict, so source is not getting computed immediately.  Instead of trying to track down each statement that's lazily evaluated, just add `{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}` to the top of your file and change `let newMap = ...` to `let !newMap = ...`.  That's it.

There are techniques for manually tracking down and eliminating laziness, but bang patterns are by far the easiest and fastest technique that I've seen.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have tried this. See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
liftIO $ atomically $ modifyTVar' (buildIndex nextKey serialized) tvi
```

instead of

```
liftIO $ do indexed <- readTVarIO tvi
         let !newIndex = buildIndex nextKey serialized indexed
         atomically $ writeTVar tvi $! newIndex
```

See the docs for [modifyTVar'](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/stm/latest/doc/html/Control-Concurrent-STM-TVar.html#v:modifyTVar-39-) and [what is weak head normal form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872898/haskell-what-is-weak-head-normal-form)