# Haskell $! operator and infinite lists

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I read that the $! operator forces strict evaluation. So why does this still work?

```
Prelude> take 10 $! repeat 1
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

I was expecting ghc to grind away forever trying to evaluate the infinite list of 1's.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`$!` forces its second argument to *weak head normal form*, which basically means it evaluates its argument's outermost constructor. So in your case, it will not force the evaluation of the whole list, but only evaluate the outermost (i.e. first) `:` constructor.

There is a good explanation of normal form vs WHNF at [Haskell: What is Weak Head Normal Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872898/haskell-what-is-weak-head-normal-form) .

Note that if you forced evaluation of the whole list (e.g. using the `$!!` operator from the `Control.DeepSeq` module), your program would not terminate:

```
λ: import Control.DeepSeq (($!!))
λ: take 10 $!! repeat 1
^C
```

Comment: The linked SO thread on Weak Head Normal Form is a great read, thanks!

Comment: Note also that `take n`, for `n > 0`, has to force the list to WHNF anyway, so `take 10 $! repeat 1` is operationally the same as `take 10 $ repeat 1`.