# My safeMapM won't catch any exceptions

Tags: exception, haskell

I'm trying to make a safe version of `mapM` that will exclude an element from the result if it throws an exception when executed.

```
safeMapM :: (a -> IO b) -> [a] -> IO [b]
safeMapM f []       = return []
safeMapM f (x : xs) = do
    restResult <- safeMapM f xs
    appliedResult <- onException (f x >>= evaluate . Just) (return Nothing)
    case appliedResult of
        Just x' -> return $ x' : restResult
        Nothing -> return restResult
```

It fails to catch anything though. In a simple test case:

```
safeMapM (\n -> return $ if n == 3 then error $ show n else n) [1,2,3,4,5]
```

it fails with:

```
*** Exception: 3
[1,2,"ghci>"
```

Why isn't it being caught? Does `evaluate` not evaluate it fully enough for the `error` to be caught? Is there a way around this without requiring that the signature be changed to `safeMapM :: (NFData a, NFData b) => (a -> IO b) -> [a] -> IO [b]`, and using `deepseq`?

Comment: `evaluate` only evaluates to WHNF.  In this case, that's the `Just` wrapper that you add just prior to calling `evaluate`.  Remove the `Just` and modify your function accordingly, and it should catch this error.  It still won't catch everything without using `deepseq` though.

Comment: This is the reason why I avoid `error` and other asynchronous exceptions: they are much more difficult to catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`evaluate x` only evaluates `x` far enough to get it into [WHNF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872898/haskell-what-is-weak-head-normal-form), and `Just x` is already in WHNF even with `x` a completely unevaluated thunk. So you have `evaluate (Just x)`, which doesn't involve evaluating `x` at all!

Instead of binding `f x` to the function `evaluate . Just`, you need to use a function that will evaluate `x` *before* wrapping it in a `Just`, something like this:

```
returnEval :: Monad m => a -> IO (m a)
returnEval x = evaluate x >>= return . return
```

With that function, you can rewrite your evaluating line like so:

```
appliedResult <- onException (f x >>= returnEval) (return Nothing)
```

With that change, the result of your expression goes from `[1,2,**exception**]` to an immediate exception. Which brings us to the next point: `onException` is not a "catch" block, it is more like finally: "If something goes wrong, run this code, but in either case give me back the first expression". If you change this to use `catch` instead, you finally end up with the behavior you wanted to begin with: `[1,2,4,5]`.

```
module SafeEval where
import Control.Exception

returnEval :: Monad m => a -> IO (m a)
returnEval x = evaluate x >>= return . return

safeMapM :: (a -> IO b) -> [a] -> IO [b]
safeMapM f []       = return []
safeMapM f (x : xs) = do
    restResult <- safeMapM f xs
    appliedResult <- catch (f x >>= returnEval) (\e -> (e :: SomeException) `seq` return Nothing)
    case appliedResult of
        Just x' -> return $ x' : restResult
        Nothing -> return restResult
```

But as John L says in the comments, this still only catches exceptions at the topmost level: those that are necessary to get into WHNF. If you really want to force eager evaluation of an entire nested expression (you probably don't), you will need a blunter instrument, such as deepseq.