# Running out of memory while counting characters in a large file

Tags: haskell, out-of-memory

I want to count the number of occurrences of each character in a large file. Although I know that counting should be implemented in a strict way in Haskell (which I tried to achieve using foldl'), I am still running out of memory. For comparison: the file size is about 2GB, while the computer has 100GB of memory. There are not many different characters in that file - maybe 20. What am I doing wrong?

```
ins :: [(Char,Int)] -> Char -> [(Char,Int)]
ins [] c = [(c,1)]
ins ((c,i):cs) d
    | c == d = (c,i+1):cs
    | otherwise = (c,i) : ins cs d

main = do
    [file] <- getArgs
    txt <- readFile file
    print $ foldl' ins [] txt
```

Comment: I recommend you read about [What is Weak Head Normal Form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872898/haskell-what-is-weak-head-normal-form)

Comment: This works fine with `ins m c = Map.insertWith' (+) c (1::Int) m`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `ins` function is creating tons of [thunks](https://wiki.haskell.org/Thunk) that cause a lot of [memory leak](https://wiki.haskell.org/Memory_leak). `foldl'` only evaluates to [weak head normal form](https://wiki.haskell.org/Weak_head_normal_form) which is not enough here. What you need is [`deepseq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-1.4.2.0/docs/Control-DeepSeq.html#v:deepseq) from `Control.DeepSeq` in order to get to *normal form*.

Alternatively, instead of association list, use [`Data.Map.Strict`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.8.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html) for counting. Also, If your IO is on the order of 2GB, you better use [lazy `ByteString`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.1/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy-Char8.html) instead of plain strings.

Bellow code should perform in constant memory space regardless of size of input:

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Data.Map.Strict (empty, alter)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B

main :: IO ()
main = getArgs >>= B.readFile . head >>= print . B.foldl' go empty
  where
  go = flip $ alter inc
  inc :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
  inc Nothing  = Just 1
  inc (Just i) = Just $ i + 1
```

Comment: I generally don't recommend `deepseq` except for parallel programming. While it will work okay in this case, it is overkill even here--it can be expected to force twice as much as necessary! In other contexts, it's much worse. Also, `Data.Bytestring.Char8` is not at all appropriate for counting *characters*, unless the input is known to be restricted to something ASCII-like. Finally, `Data.Map` is not ideal for maps with small keys. It's typically much better to use `IntMap` and convert `Char` to and from `Int`.

Comment: That really helped! Thanks a lot!