# Weak head normal form and normal form

Tags: haskell

I have question about weak head normal form and normal form.

**Weak head normal form means, the expression will only evaluate as far as necessary to reach to a data constructor.**

**Normal form means, the expression will be fully evaluated.**

Now, I have following expression:

```
\x -> x * 10
```

Why the expression above is in normal form?

```
"Papu" ++ "chon"
```

Why the expression above is in neither WHNF nor NF?

Comment: You've answered your own questions: 1) because "the expression [is] fully evaluated". 2) because "the expression [is not] evaluate[d] as far as necessary to reach to a data constructor". Perhaps you should state what about these definitions is unclear to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WHNF evaluates far enough to reach a data constructor *or lambda function*.

If you have a lambda function that hasn't been called with an argument, you cannot evaluate it any further anyway. So a lambda function is in WHNF, and indeed NF, since there is nothing to evaluate further. Now, if you *call* the lambda function with an argument, we can evaluate what the result might be. But the lambda function on its own? Nothing further to be done.

Your first expression is a lambda function with no arguments. It is therefor in normal form.

Your second expression is neither a data constructor nor a lambda, hence is not in any normal form. Now, if you evaluate it for one step, you obtain

```
'P' : ("apu" ++ "chon")
```

Which (although the syntax doesn't look like it) begins with a data constructor (namely `(:)`), and hence *is* in WHNF, but *not* NF (since it still contains the unevaluated `(++)` subexpression).

Perhaps it's easier if we get rid on the infix syntax:

```
(++) "Papu" "chon"
```

vs

```
(:) 'P' ( (++) "apu" "chon" )
```

Comment: Actually, normal form of a lambda term traditionally has meant evaluating as much as possible under the lambda. `\x -> (1 + 1) + x` is not in normal form, as it could be reduced to `\x -> 2 + x`

Comment: Isn't there a requirement for the data constructor in WHNF to be *lazy*?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> \x -> x * 10
> ```
>
> Why the expression above is in normal form?

Because, you can't simplify it.

---

> ```
> "Papu" ++ "chon"
> ```
>
> Why the expression above is in neither WHNF nor NF?

First of all, if some expression in NF - that means it's in WHNF. NF it's more restricted version of WHNF.

So, We can restructure your question.
**Why the expression above isn't in WHNF?**

Simple answer is: We can simplify it to `"Papuchon"`.

---

If you want to know what difference between WHNF and NF, you can read, for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872898/haskell-what-is-weak-head-normal-form).

Comment: About the lambda expression, what does it mean `simplify`?

Comment: You can `simplify` some expression if it has subexpression which is `lambda application` and you can reduce it (apply it). Or more simpler, you can call function and get result. In your example, you can't calculate `x * 10`, because you don't known an `x` value.

Comment: @zero_coding For instance, `\x -> 5+5` and `\x -> id x` can be simplifed / reduced, so they are not NF. `\x -> x (id 5)` can also be reduced, since `id 5` can. Instead, `\x -> x 5` can not be reduced, since we do not know what `x` is, so the lambda is in NF. `\x -> x+x` is also a NF.

Comment: @chi and MathematicalOrchid: you have two different notions of NF (chi is happy to reduce under lambdas when MathematicalOrchid is not). This could be confusing for the reader.

Comment: @freestyle `\x -> 5+5` I can simplify/reduce to `\x -> 10` right?

Comment: @zero_coding Yes, you can. More over, you must to do that for transform to NF.

Comment: @zero_coding But in Haskell is convention that WHNF equivalent to NF for functions. (see `instance NFData (a -> b)`)

Comment: @gallais Good point. I guess it depends on the context. In some theories, reductions under lambdas are allowed. In most implementations of functional languages, however, we don't reduce under lambdas.

Comment: can `'P' : "apuchon"` be simplified? isn't it in WHNF though?

Comment: @WillNess `"apuchon"` its just syntactic sugar, so `'P' : "apuchon"` ~ `'P':'a':'p':'u':'c':'h':'o':'n':[]`.

Comment: that's an irrelevant (here) detail. so, can `'P' : ("apu" ++ "chon")` be simplified? is it in WHNF?

Comment: @WillNess It can be simplified (it isn't in NF) and it's in WHNF (top redex is construct application and it cant be reduced to something).