# how to print the iterations inside a Haskell recursion call?

Tags: haskell, recursion

Considering the code below which returns the factorial of  a number:

```
factorial n = go n 1
  where
    go n ret | n > 1 = go (n-1) (ret * n)
             | otherwise = ret
```

how can I print `n` in every single recursive call of `go n ret`? Since `n` is being decremented each time, I want to see if I can print it every time it gets decremented (like `5 4 3 2 1`).
This is how I tried to do it (which is totally wrong) but I can't think of a different way:

```
factorial n = go n 1
  where
    go n ret | n > 1 = go (n-1) (ret * n) print n
             | otherwise = ret
```

Comment: For debugging purposes you could use Debug.Trace: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The type

To print, you'll need to lift the value into the I/O Applicative; the type will change from

```
factorial :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> a
```

to

```
factorial :: (Num a, Ord a, Show a) => a -> IO a
```

#### What the `go` action does

The `go` action needs to do two things:

1. print the number `n`
2. either recursively call `go` or produce the result

#### How to do two I/O actions sequentially

To do two things, we need some combinator to combine them. The appropriate one here is [`*>`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-42--62-):

> `(*>) :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f b`
>
> Sequence actions, discarding the value of the first argument.

This is exactly what we need because we don't need to use the value of the first action (the type of the [`print`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:print) action is `IO ()`, so it doesn't contain any useful result).

#### Lifting a value into I/O

We also need [`pure`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:pure) at the end

> `pure :: Applicative f => a -> f a`
>
> Lift a value.

to lift the result into the I/O Applicative.

#### The code

```
factorial n = go n 1
  where
    go n acc =
      print n *>
      if n > 1
        then let !acc' = acc * n
             in  go (n-1) acc'
        else pure acc
```

The `!` in the binding of `acc'` [forces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993112/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-mean-in-a-haskell-declaration) the multiplication to occur immediately (thanks to [Daniel Wagner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48845978/402884) for pointing out the need for this).

Testing in GHCi:

```
λ> factorial 5 >>= print
5
4
3
2
1
120
```

Comment: (And don't forget to use `$!` or similar to interleave the multiplications with the printing.)

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is you are trying to do some IO (`print`) within a pure function (`factorial`): you can't do so in Haskell.

One workaround is to use the module `Debug.Trace` likewise:

```
import Debug.Trace

factorial n = go n 1
  where
  go n ret | ("n value is: " ++ show n) `trace` n > 1 = go (n-1) (ret * n)
           | otherwise = ret
```

And you'll get:

```
*Main Debug.Trace> factorial 5
n value is: 5
n value is: 4
n value is: 3
n value is: 2
n value is: 1
120
```

There are some caveats though as stated in the library:

> The trace function should only be used for debugging, or for
>   monitoring execution. The function is not referentially transparent:
>   its type indicates that it is a pure function but it has the side
>   effect of outputting the trace message.

As Daniel pointed out, if we want to enforce the multiplication to occur in each step of the evaluation, we have to rewrite this as follows:

```
factorial n = go n 1
  where
  go n ret | ("n value is: " ++ show n) `trace` n > 1 = go (n-1) $! (ret * n)
           | otherwise = ret
```

Comment: And the caveat I called out about laziness in my answer applies here, as well, of course: none of the multiplications are done until all of the printing has already finished, which probably is not the desired behavior. It can be fixed in the same way as in my answer, by inserting a `$!` between `go (n-1)` and `(ret * n)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(>>)` to sequence `IO` actions and `return` to turn pure computations into `IO` actions. So:

```
factorial n = go n 1 where
    go n ret | n > 1 = print n >> go (n-1) (ret*n)
             | otherwise = return ret
```

Of course, `factorial` is now a function that produces an `IO` action; its callers may need to be fixed up to accommodate that.

Also, beware: due to laziness, none of the actual multiplications are done until *after* all of the printing! This is *probably* not what you intended. It won't matter much for the kinds of tests you'll be doing on a microbenchmark like this, but for larger functions that do more computation per iteration you might start to notice. You can fix this using `$!` or similar to make the computation of the `IO` action depend on the computation of this iteration's work. So:

```
factorial n = go n 1 where
    go n ret | n > 1 = print n >> (go (n-1) $! ret*n)
             | otherwise = return ret
```