# What data {-# UNPACK #-} !Size !a !(Set a) !(Set a) means in Haskell

Tags: haskell, set

I am not familiar with Haskell but want to check out some of its definitions. I am looking at the [Set](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/src/Data.Set.Internal.html#Set) and see this:

```
data Set a    = Bin {-# UNPACK #-} !Size !a !(Set a) !(Set a)
              | Tip
```

Wondering what that comment is doing (if it's doing some sort of code injection magic), and what the meaning of the exclamation marks is and the overall statement of `!Size !a !(Set a) !(Set a)`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a GHC pragma:

> The UNPACK indicates to the compiler that it should unpack the contents of a constructor field into the constructor itself, removing a level of indirection.

src: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.3/docs/html/users_guide/pragmas.html

The meaning of those exclamations marks is to enforce strictness on those fields.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: @LancePollard Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993112/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-mean-in-a-haskell-declaration/993122#993122